# Best way to search a comma separated mysql field

Tags: php, mysql

I have been given the task to combine 2 mysql fields into one and then make it so that the new field can be searched. The 2 fields I had to combine in my database where previous year registered and current years registered. The format both these fields are in are dd/mm/yyyy. I have combined these fields into a field called Years Registered whih is still in the same format dd/mm/yyyy but has the years registered seperated by a comma(,). I am wondering how I would go about performing a couple different kinds of querys on this column. The mysql queries I have to perform are: Show All() , Show All between dates: mm/yyyy and mm/yyyy   , Before: mm/yyyy , After: mm/yyyy

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems that previous table structure was better than current.

Comment: It would be better if you store dates with right data type, that is date and not varchar. 
Take a look at str_to_date() function and keep table normalized as already suggested.

Comment: see they want to have it so every year they can edit the column to add the new year registered, any ideas?

Comment: Whoever gave you that task is under the illusion they're a database designer. They're not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like it but if you need you can use the next solution:

extract date using start_date = STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(your_new_field, 1, 10)) 
and end_date=STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(your_new_field, 12, 10))

Comment: Hmm see the problem with this is though every year a business has been registered with the company it will be added on so you could eventually have a string such as dd/mm/yyyy,dd/mm/yyyy,dd/mm/yyyy,dd/mm/yyyy and so on

Comment: I see. But you can have additional table with two columns id_from_this_table, date_registered. When you create form for client you can simple combine dates and therefore parse this one before saving. In this case you should join 2 tables when it's necessary to create complicated query.

Comment: Thanks andrej I will take your approach, I was kind of thinking this myself after reading that normalization page

Answer (score 2):

**Do not do this!**
I do not know how it is exactly possible (some SQL Stringoperations and Datefunctions in a storedprocedurem i presume), but it will surely kill performance of your database.
use a relation for this.

This  is:

- way faster
- more expandable (eg. for three dates..)
- easier to code
- much better understandable
- more portable to other databases

If you have problems with existing platforms you have to support, use a code base where both alternatives are supported. This is still easier and better to maintain than to use a comma-separated list

Answer (score 0):

Your database would be breaking 'First Normalized Form (1NF)' and would be *highly* ineffecient.

In order to search for a selected date, you would either have to query all rows in the table, or use `LIKE` which is also very sluggish.

Whoever is asking you to do this should read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) on database normalization.

What is wrong with using two `DATE`, or `DATETIME` fields and the formatting them outside of MySQL?